# My YouTube embed won't work on my website

Tags: html, youtube, embed

[`My Page`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AW01S.png)

> This is my embedded code, I tried getting YouTube videos to update automatically

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item1" vnum='0' cid="UC96WWrjtdDu1kKQztFJoqWg" width="600" height="340" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item2" vnum='1' cid="UC96WWrjtdDu1kKQztFJoqWg" width="600" height="340" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item3" vnum='2' cid="UC96WWrjtdDu1kKQztFJoqWg" width="600" height="340" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item4" vnum='3' cid="UC96WWrjtdDu1kKQztFJoqWg" width="600" height="340" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to provide the latest video on your page by including JavaScript. I found it in this article:

https://codegena.com/auto-embed-latest-video-youtube-channel/

You can see it on Codepen here:

https://codepen.io/St3ph3n92/pen/rNONYMN?editors=1010

```
    const reqURL = "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=" + 
    encodeURIComponent("https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=");
    function loadVideo(iframe){
         $.getJSON( reqURL + iframe.getAttribute('cid'),
          function(data) {
             let videoNumber = (iframe.getAttribute('vnum')? 
   Number(iframe.getAttribute('vnum')):0);
        console.log(videoNumber);
         let link = data.items[videoNumber].link;
         id = link.substr(link.indexOf("=") + 1);  
         iframe.setAttribute("src","https://youtube.com/embed/"+id + "? 
        controls=0&autoplay=1");
        }
      );
    }
    let iframes = document.getElementsByClassName('latestVideoEmbed');
    for (let i = 0, len = iframes.length; i < len; i++){
           loadVideo(iframes[I]);
    }
```

Note that you will also need to include the jquery library:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you are aiming to avoid using JavaScript, in the same article mentioned above, there is the option of embedding with this iframe:

```
<iframe width="600" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?max-results=1&controls=0&showinfo=0&rel=0&listType=user_uploads&list=YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME_HERE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the help, I'm new to this much appreciated

Comment: No problem :) Best of luck.